# Twitter client application with twitter streaming API in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I want to implement some of the twitter's client application's features in a web application, for example updating the timeline and searching for users etc. Now from what i found out by searching is, to do this in real time without refreshing a page or time delay, i would need to implement twitter's streaming API(user stream). I understand the twitter's REST API but unfortunately, i cant get the concept of streaming around my head. The documentation didn't help much either. For example about keeping a connection open and populate the page with real time tweets. I am planning to do this with PHP. Can anyone provide me an insight on how to go around doing it and what library to use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try phirehose. Supports Streaming API and REST API as well. Check its [Introduction page](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose/wiki/Introduction) in the Wiki to understand how phirehose handles the Streaming API.

https://github.com/fennb/phirehose